# 'talking about' vs 'talk about'

Tags: tenses, present-tense, present-progressive

I came across the following sentence on the internet:

"When we are talking about possession, relationships, illnesses and characteristics of people or things we can use either have or have got."

Is it correct to say "When we are **talking** about [...]"?

In my opinion the simple present (to **talk** about sth.) seems more appropriate.

Comment: It's correct. Why do you think the simple present is more appropriate?

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you for your comment. As far as I'm concerned, the present progressive doesn't sound right in that context since the phrase "When we are talking about sth." is more like a general statement. General statements, however, require the simple present.

Comment: Agree with that general statements usually have the simple present. But maybe it isn't a general statement. Maybe it wants to add contrast, therefore, it is using the present progressive: *When we are talking about ..., and only then ...* or *When we are talking about ... as opposed to ...* Maybe the writer discussed other topics before this one.